# Serial number for each item

Tags: 7, commerce

I am making a book rental cum selling site. I have planned to use Drupal Commerce for it. But tracking the item is simply not possible & so that I am trying to find the solution for assigning serial number for each number of items(attributes) for drupal commerce product.

Like I am having a BOOK & it has 10 copy, so I want to keep one unique serial number for each copy.

If somebody have any idea about this then please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by first creating a Book Product (Non-Fiction) and issuing a specific sku number for each separate Book Title that I would introduce as a specific product. Combining this with the http://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock module might be useful in allowing unique skus per book but than also having quantity of books in stock for multiple copies.

1. Ender's Game (10 copies according to commerce_stock) SKU #00000001
2. Dune(30 copies according to commerce_stock) SKU #00000002

Comment: I want to keep different SKU for different copy as I am making library. Suppose I have "Ender's Game" 5 copies then I would like to have #0000001,#0000002,#0000003,#0000004,#0000005...

Comment: Drupal commerce is built to class product types to have unique skus for individual products. You could feasibly create a product type like "Non-fiction Hardback." and enter in individual copies of content as having specific SKUs WITH similar names.

Comment: But If I will have same title again & again...it will show multiple times in the list of available item list to sell or rent...

Comment: Updated my answer to account for that, please take a look and mark if that fixes it.

Comment: We have come again on same place where I were. Thing is..I am able to maintain stock by number of copies, but as I told...I want a unique serial number for each copies so that I can track each copy while renting... Suppose I am having two copy of a title...then by unique serial number I can see which user of mine is having which copy of the title...